# Verify if inherited super class method was called from method being tested or not

Tags: java, spring, mockito

Ok so I'm stuck with Mockito again. Here's the situation:

I've a super class, and a subclass:

```
class Parent {
    protected void insertData() { 
        // Here is some database related stuff
        someObject.storeData();
    }
}


class Child extends Parent {

    private String name;

    public void printHierarchy(int x) {
        if (x > 1) {
            insertData()
        } else {
            System.out.println("Child");
        }

    }
}
```

And in my unit test class, I'm testing `Child` class `printHierarchy()` method:

```
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
public class ChildTest {

    @InjectMocks  // To inject mock objects
    private Child child = new Child();    

    @Before
    public void setUp() {
        MockitoAnnotations.initMocks(this);
        // This is where the issue is
        doNothing().when(child).insertData();
    }

    @Test
    public void testPrintHierarchy() {
        child.printHierarchy(5);
        // Here also
        verify(child, times(1)).insertData();
    }
}
```

So the issue is, how do I verify if `insertData()` method was called from `Child#printHierachy()`?

When I try the above code, I get the error as:

```
Argument passed to when() is not a mock!
```

Of course, `child` is not a mock. I'm testing that class. But how do I resolve this issue?

No I haven't found any duplicate of this. One question was pretty similar though, but it didn't help me.

Comment: Almost (but not quite) a duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10092926/verifying-sequence-of-private-method-calls-in-unit-testing

Answer (score 3):

You need to use `spy()` for that. The following code works:

```
public final class Bin
{
    @Test
    public void spyMe()
    {
        final Child c = spy(new Child());
        doNothing().when(c).printParent();
        c.printHierarchy(1);
        verify(c).printParent();
    }
}

class Parent {
    protected void printParent() { System.exit(0);}
}

class Child extends Parent {

    private String name;

    public void printHierarchy(int i) {
        if (i > 0)
            printParent();
    }
}
```

Comment: Ok, I just tried with `spy()`, but it isn't working. What happens to the references in a class when we use spy? Are they null? Currently I was injecting some mock objects into it using @InjectMocks

Comment: What do you mean by "references in a class"?

Comment: The `Child` class contains some other objects. Which I'm mocking and injecting. Will those be `null` when I use `@Spy`?

Comment: Cannot tell, really... I do "inject" mocks but by invoking constructors, and `spy()` works for me in that case as well. No idea for annotations, I don't use them, but I don't see why it would be any different...

Answer (score 1):

Whether method `printHierachy()` calls method `printParent()` is surely an implementation detail of method `printHierachy()`, and so should not be tested for. Unit tests should check that a method has the required outputs.

For printing methods, checking the format of the printed output would do. For a method that updates a data-base, check that the data-base contains the expected values. For a method that manipulates a domain-model object in a specified manner, check that the domain object is in the correct state. And so on.

Comment: Actually that's not the real scenario. The `printParent()` method is actually inserting something into database. And the method is invoked based on some condition. I need to check if the method is invoked for that condition. Perhaps I'll update my question.

Answer (score 1):

I think you need to use a spy for Child instead of a mock.

Answer (score 0):

I think the mistake may be conceptual. If `Child` extends `Parent`, then the methods of `Parent` are part of the implementation, i.e. the System Under Test.

**If the `Parent` needs to be mocked independently of the `Child`**, then maybe you should use composition instead of inheritance:

```
public class Child {
    private Parent parent;

    public void printHierarchy() {
        parent.printParent();
    }

    // setters/getters
}
```

Now the `Parent` is mockable and you can test whether `printParent()` was called or not.

**If the class hierarchy is conceptually correct**, then you should *not* need to test internal implementation details (i.e. that the interface/public method calls some other). You do not care about implementation details.